# MeteorJS - FlowRouter random redirect (instance)

Tags: javascript, meteor, flow-router

Hi everyone im new to meteor and to coding generaly, Im trying to redirect a user to a page with random ending (make instances of the same page per user so other users cannot acces the same page)
for example I have:

```
 FlowRouter.route('/main',{ name: 'main', action(){ BlazeLayout.render('MainLayout'); } });
```

I want the user to be redirected to something like:

```
/main=randomString
```

(so it will be unique to every user that hits the Main page) help?

Answer (score 1):

Issue solved!

```
FlowRouter.go('/main', {Room: "RoomID"}, {Num: "RandomNumber"});
```

made it happen, redirects me to /main=randomNumber for making multiple instances with unique path for every user